# download progress with playwright

Tags: c#, playwright

Is there a way to get the percentage of the downloading process when using Playwright?

This is the code I use to download files:

```
using (var playWright = await Playwright.CreateAsync()) 
{ 
string fileName = null, path = null; 
BrowserTypeLaunchOptions browserLaunchOptions = new BrowserTypeLaunchOptions() { Headless = true}; 
var browser = await playWright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(browserLaunchOptions); 
var browserContextOptions = new BrowserNewContextOptions() { AcceptDownloads = true }; 
var context = await browser.NewContextAsync(browserContextOptions); 
var page = await context.NewPageAsync(); 
page.Download += async (object sender, IDownload e) => { string path = DownloadDirectory + @"\" + e.SuggestedFilename;
await e.SaveAsAsync(path); }; 
await page.GotoAsync(URL);
}
```

Comment: Download progress indication is not yet possible, I would recommend to file a feature request on GitHub.